# Error while testing Google Dialog Bot. Unable to send Uttarance file to bot : botium box

Tags: testing, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I am using commercial version of Botium box. able to connect to Google dialog bot and able to add test set which contains 2 utterance file and one convo file. on Running the Test Set getting this error (Unable to send utterance file to bot):

[image]
[image]

Addition Figure no 001 :- Screenshot of Chatting Manually with Bot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RNjB.png)

Error:

```
Error: bot_first_reply/bot_first_reply-L1/Step 1 - tell utterance: error sending to bot 
Error: Cannot send message to dialog flow container: { 
Error: Deadline exceeded 
  at Http2CallStream.call.on (/app/agent/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:45) 
  at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:202:15) 
  at process.nextTick (/app/agent/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22) 
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:9) code: 4, details: 'Deadline exceeded', metadata: Metadata { options: undefined, internalRepr: Map {} } } 
  at sessionClient.detectIntent.then.catch.err (/app/agent/node_modules/botium-connector-dialogflow/dist/botium-connector-dialogflow-cjs.js:704:16)
```

Comment: Looks like dialogflow doesn't deliver response in time (I google for the error message). Does your dialogflow agent include a fulfillment webhook which times out  maybe ?

Comment: @FlorianTreml i think fulfillment Web-hook is working fine because we are getting response from bot when we are chatting manually with the bot. should i provide you the url, you can also have a look into this?

Comment: @FlorianTreml , just added the screenshot of the chat with bot in the post. Figure no :- 001 . Click on "enter image description here" link.

Comment: could you give me access to the dialogflow project so i can have a look myself florian.treml @ botium.at

Comment: @FlorianTreml , I have mailed you the required details.

Comment: not received email up to now

Comment: @FlorianTreml , i have mailed you at provided email id - florian.treml@botium.at  with subject -"Error while testing Google Dialog Bot. Unable to send Uttarance file to bot : botium box" stackoverflow Issue | Configuration file. Could you please check once if the email id is correct or did you got the mail with such subject line?